# How to base64 encode an image from the facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I am attempting to convert an image url provided by the facebook api into base64 format with cURL.

the api provides a url as such:

```
https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/p180x540/72099_736078480783_68792122_n.jpg?oh=f3698c5eed12c1f2503b147d221f39d1&oe=54C5BA4E&__gda__=1418090980_c7af12de6b0dd8abe752f801c1d61e0d
```

The issue is that the url only works with the oh, oe and **gda** parameters included in the url string, there is no direct img url. Removing the params send you to a facebook error page.

With the parameterized url my curl_exec is not getting correct image data. Is there a way to get the base64 data from facebook, or is there something I can do to get access the pure image url given the parameterized url?

This is what my decode scrip looks like:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

  $url = $_GET['url'];

  try {
        $c = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3);

        $result = curl_exec($c);
        curl_close ($c);

        if(false===$result) {
           echo 'fail';
        } else {
           $base64 = "data:image/jpeg;charset=UTF-8;base64,".base64_encode($result);
           echo $base64;
}
} catch ( \ErrorException $e ) {
    echo 'fail';
}
```

Comment: It seems most likely your curl command isn't actually hitting the correct URL (i.e with all of the parameters) - have you ruled that out?

Answer (score 0):

To address your specific problem, your script is likely failing because the required `oh`, `oe`, `__gda__` parameters are getting separated during the GET request and therefore are not included in `$_GET['url']`.

Make sure you're using a URL-encoded string so any unencoded `&` characters aren't handled as delimiters. Then just decode the string before passing it on to cURL.

```
...

$url = urldecode($_GET['url']);

...
```

---

For anyone curious, you can still load any Facebook image from any one of their legacy CDNs without needing the new parameters:

1. `https://scontent-a-iad.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc3/`
2. `https://scontent-b-iad.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc3/`
3. `https://scontent-c-iad.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc3/`

Just append the original image filename to the URL [et voila](https://scontent-c-iad.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc3/72099_736078480783_68792122_n.jpg).

*Disclaimer: I have no idea how long this little trick will work for so don't use it on anything important in production.*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this won't help much but it seems that the original picture (ending with `_o`) does not need *gda* nor *oe oh* parameters

to get the original profile picture you can do:

```
var username_or_id = "name.lastname" //Example
get_url ("http://graph.facebook.com/$username_or_id/picture?width=9999")
```

hth

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. My solution:

```
$url = urldecode($url);
return base64_encode(file_get_contents($url));
```

Where the URL is to Graph API:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/$user_id/picture?width=160
```

(You probably want to also check, if file_get_contents returns something)

Answer (score -2):

You just need to add the **CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER** set to **false** as the url from **facebook is https and not http.**, or you could just as well request the url without ssl by replacing https with http.

Try the code below

```
    $url = 'https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/p180x540/72099_736078480783_68792122_n.jpg?oh=f3698c5eed12c1f2503b147d221f39d1&oe=54C5BA4E&__gda__=1418090980_c7af12de6b0dd8abe752f801c1d61e0d';

try {
    $c = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3);

    /***********************************************/
    // you need the curl ssl_opt_verifypeer
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    /***********************************************/

    $result = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close ($c);

    if(false===$result) {
       echo 'fail';
    } else {
       $base64 = '<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/jpeg;charset=UTF-8;base64,'.base64_encode($result).'"/>';
       echo $base64;
    }
} 
catch ( \ErrorException $e ) {
    echo 'fail';
}
```

Comment: if this has answered your question please accept this answer

Comment: `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` has nothing to do with this. The [purpose](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.html) of that option is to bypass verification of the server's SSL certificate. Considering Akamai is not using self-signed certs on any of their publicly accessible CDNs, it doesn't matter if you verify it or not.

Comment: "Is there a way to get the base64 data from facebook", CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER resolves the issue, that option has everything in resolving the issue, please read the question

Comment: That doesn't even make sense. Try your code with it set either way and you'll see it has no effect.

Comment: i try all my code before making assumptions on how to resolve the issue, i thought stackoveflow had people with programming experience and not some newbies giving opinions left and right...

Comment: any https site resource can be accessed either with the  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER set to false or by replacing the https with http in the url, been working with curl problems for more than 2 years and i can say it works with a local server and dedicated hosting, assuming you have the curl option enabled in php.ini ... either way i wont add any more answers to this site, people talk trash about things they didn`t even worked with

Comment: @CodeWriter - There will always be people that disagree with you. Please do not let this sceanrio deter your time in here. I used your code and it worked PERFECTLY. And I thank you sir...