# How to get big facebook video thumbnail

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I'm looking for the way to get big facebook video thumbnail.
i've found some links:

http://graph.facebook.com/1571886379501082/picture
~> this one retun one small thumbnail picture with size 128x128.

and other one 
http://graph.facebook.com/1571886379501082/thumbnails
~> this one will return big thumbnail picture but it required access_token to get.

is it possible to get big thumbnail video picture without login on facebook?

Comment: The `picture` edge of a node is the only thing that still works without any access token (intended use is to display user profile pictures, without requiring the viewing user to login first.) _Everything else_ needs an access token from API v2 on. If you don’t want to force your app users to login, then fetch the data server-side, using an app or page access token.

Answer (score -1):

When the first URL is hit, the link is refering to

[https://fbcdn-vthumb-a.akamaihd.net/hvthumb-ak-xfa1/v/t15.0-10/p128x128/10876207_805883852835396_1769147834_n.jpg?oh=a755047c692902070f8d9bd79ce28453&oe=56396042&**gda**=1451498989_6c4cbd42045490d0935990d6627905ed](https://fbcdn-vthumb-a.akamaihd.net/hvthumb-ak-xfa1/v/t15.0-10/p128x128/10876207_805883852835396_1769147834_n.jpg?oh=a755047c692902070f8d9bd79ce28453&oe=56396042&__gda__=1451498989_6c4cbd42045490d0935990d6627905ed)

For large thumbnail you have to change the size **128x128** to **552x414**

[https://fbcdn-vthumb-a.akamaihd.net/hvthumb-ak-xfa1/v/t15.0-10/s552x414/10876207_805883852835396_1769147834_n.jpg?oh=09f92535e931ff2269a7ae4d31c03d5b&oe=563FEF44&**gda**=1451103467_d60d0b95c7e93f9c9046a0eeeca24c5e](https://fbcdn-vthumb-a.akamaihd.net/hvthumb-ak-xfa1/v/t15.0-10/s552x414/10876207_805883852835396_1769147834_n.jpg?oh=09f92535e931ff2269a7ae4d31c03d5b&oe=563FEF44&__gda__=1451103467_d60d0b95c7e93f9c9046a0eeeca24c5e)

Kindly figure out with regular expression or something else for proper usage but the above URL works for me.

Comment: i've changed thumbnail size path before but didn't work. did you ever notice the string behind gda parameter? how to get these string? if this string is not correct, you'll fail to get image thumbnail.

Comment: Yes! creating GDA parameter is an obstacle but you can resolved by following this topic which has some reg-ex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002222/how-to-base64-encode-an-image-from-the-facebook-api

Comment: i've read your article, but didn't see any way to get oh or gad parameters. can you tell me more detail?

Answer (score -1):

This method will create an object array and seek the last key of the format, which is the big image.

```
$fb = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/1246538155392772');
$fb = json_decode($fb);

//---find the big image which is always last in array
$key = count($fb->format)-1;
$bigimg = $fb->format[$key]->picture;
echo '<img src="'.$bigimg.'" />';
```

If you just want to get the image for simple posting, just use this tool. [Get Facebook Video Images](http://videoimages.websitedons.net/)