# Convert a div's content to Image after it is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Lots of searching but still couldn't get pass through this problem.
I have a following div where a photo from facebook server is loaded using graph api. I want a way to convert the content of div into image so that i could save it to server and upload it to facebook. Please can anyone help me!!!

```
<div>  
     <h1>My pic </h1>       
     <?php echo "<img src='https://graph.facebook.com/481032075371655/picture'>";?>             
</div>
```

Comment: seriously!!! noone have answered this question still....

Comment: content of the div is already an image, why you're trying to convert the div to image then?

Comment: @AminurRashid i have added h1 tags.. now i want a image having everything inside the div.. can u help??

Comment: Maybe adding some css?

Comment: @BoVandersteene could u please elaborate??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you. html2canvas

https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html

Comment: I have already tried it... Couldn't convert dynamically generated div to image... It will give blank picture with only h1 tags but not the image generated by php tags

Comment: I got it. Do you have a jsfiddle of it?

Comment: Well, I checked here and is it working, the content was captured and I rendered in another img. It's ok. http://jsfiddle.net/dqsnkzrx/

Comment: I want it to work for the image located in Internet... replace the  <img src="/img/logo.png" /> with <img src="https://www.graph.facebook.com/313237675736097/picture"/> and see if it still works...

Comment: oh, I got it. If you open the network tool on Chrome you will see that the image is generated with other url result. Check my fiddle again..

Comment: This guy said that he got the real Url doing this:
I had similar problem. My solution... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002222/how-to-base64-encode-an-image-from-the-facebook-api

Comment: put https:// infront of graph.facebook.com/313237675736097/picture in ur fiddle and see.. where the problem exist

Comment: Yes, I saw the problem http://jsfiddle.net/dqsnkzrx/3/ the url result is rendered only on chrome network tab, I copy the url manually and rendered on my sample.   But, there is a guy who said that he got the real Url doing this: "I had similar problem. My solution..."  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002222/how-to-base64-encode-an-image-from-the-facebook-api